# Navigation Bar not showing up for iphone 7 plus in simulator but shows for all other models?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The Navigation Bar is not showing up for iPhone 7 Plus in simulator but shows for all other models.

It may be related to how the `viewControllers` are created. They are created when a `segmentedControl` is pressed but the first `viewController` should be shown automatically:

```
// MARK: - Create Child View Controllers Programatically - Activated when Segmented Controller pressed

private func createMoviesGenresViewController() -> MoviesGenresViewController {
  // Load Storyboard
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

  // Instantiate View Controller
  let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoviesGenresViewController") as! MoviesGenresViewController
           // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
  self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

  return viewController
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with these viewcontrollers once they are created?  Maybe posting the function that calls `createMoviesGenresViewController` would help.

Comment: I have the same problem. did you find solution? if yes, could you please post it as answer?